# Word ,excel files not display in browser

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

The below code is in my .cs file.

protected void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    string strurl = "ViewFile.ashx?Name=Img/FT.pdf";//Welcome.docx";
    string StrPop = "window.open('"+strurl+"', '_newtab')";
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(sender as Control, this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", StrPop, true);
}
```

ViewFile.ashx code.

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
{

bool freeDownload = true;

```
    string supportingFile = context.Request.QueryString["Name"].ToString();
    string strpath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(supportingFile);
    string strname = Path.GetFileName(strpath);
    string strextension = Path.GetExtension(strpath);
    string strtype = "";

    if (strextension != null)
    {
        switch (strextension.ToLower())
        {
            case ".htm":
            case ".html":
                strtype = "text/HTML";
                break;

            case ".txt":
                strtype = "text/plain";
                break;
            case ".doc":
                strtype = "application/msword";
                break;
            case ".rtf":
                strtype = "application/msword";
                break;
            case ".docx":
                strtype ="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" ; //"application/msword";
                break;
            case ".xls":
                strtype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                break;
            case ".xlsx":
                strtype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                break;
            case ".pdf":
                strtype = "Application/pdf";
                break;
        }
    }
    if (freeDownload)
    {
       // context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline: filename=\"" + strname + "\"");
    }
    if (strtype != null)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(strpath);
        context.Response.ContentType = strtype;
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.Name + "\"");
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        context.Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
        context.Response.WriteFile(strpath);
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.End();

    }

}
```

please anyone help me? when i click view button if it is pdf file it is displayed in browser.but if it is .docx,doc,.xlsx,..it is going directly download . how can i display that files in browser ?

Answer (score 0):

You can on button click create a FolderBrowserDialog , give it filters to the relevant extensions and then show it to the user, like this:

```
FolderBrowserDialog browseDialog;

browseDialog.Filter=" Wordfile (*.dotm; *.dot; *.docx; *.dotx; *.doc; *.docm; *.rtf; *.txt)|*.dotm; *.dot; *.docx; *.dotx; *.doc; *.docm; *.rtf; *.txt";  

if (browseDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       MessageBox.Show( System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(browseDialog.FileName));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. can you explain how to use folderbrowserDialog in webapplicaion .i thing that your code is windows application.         if i go to use System.Windows.Form i got some error. because i use web controls.i need the solution for web Application

Comment: @user3300574, Yes, it is WinForm syntax, I suggest you to add tag of `web application` to the post, so that experts in this field could help you. Please post the answer when you manage to solve it. Thanks.